# overwrite slice of multi-index dataframe with series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe and want to set a slice of one of its columns equal to a series, ordered (sorted) according to the column slice' and series' index-match. The column's innermost index and series' index are identical, except their ordering (sorting). (see example below)

I can do this by first sorting the series' index according to the column's index and then using series.values (see below), but this feels like a workaround and I was wondering if it's possible to directly assign the series to the column slice.

example:

```
    import pandas as pd
    multi_index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a','b'],['x','y']])
    df=pd.DataFrame(0,multi_index,['p','q'])
    s1=pd.Series([1,2],['y','x'])
    df.loc['a','p']=s1[df.loc['a','p'].index].values
```

The code above gives the desired output, but I was wondering if the last line could be done simpler, e.g.:

```
    df.loc['a','p']=s1
```

but this sets the column slice to NaNs.

Desired output:

```
         p  q
    a x  2  0
      y  1  0
    b x  0  0
      y  0  0
```

obtained output from df.loc['a','p']=s1:

```
         p  q
    a x  NaN  0
      y  NaN  0
    b x  0.0  0
      y  0.0  0
```

It seems like a simple issue to me but I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that?

```
df.loc['a']['p'] = s1
```

Resulting df is here

```
     p  q
a x  2  0
  y  1  0
b x  0  0
  y  0  0
```

Comment: This works, thanks!! Is this an exception to the rule that chained indexing should not be used, because it is unreliable whether it returns a view or a copy? (https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: @alvarowier oh well, if we'll try to go depth it's really "should be avoided", but it seems to be that you're not the first person who has faced with this issue, see here -> https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22493

Comment: Update: your solution above works for the example, but when I try it in the code for which I actually needed the solution, it doesn't work; so I guess chained indexing is unreliable after all... Thanks anyway :)